# Client certificate missing from HTTPS requests following Apache to Nginx migration

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https

First, to give **some context**:

We have a server app hidden behind a TLS proxy. The proxy server asks for a client certificate, tests it against our CA and forward the request to the server in HTTP with the client cert as a header. The header is then used in the application to identify the client.

Now, **the problem** :
We switched the implementation of the proxy from Apache to Nginx a few days ago and we've discovered that *some* requests (from different clients) that used to go through don't anymore. The client certificate is declared missing by the Nginx and the request is blocked.

**What we know** :

- We compared the logs generated by the Apache proxy when receiving a request from a client that goes through and one that doesn't.

The request that goes through produces a big dump containing the client certificate:

```
ssl_engine_io.c(2070): [client 192.168.1.117:65017] OpenSSL: read 5143/5143 bytes from BIO#557fd20fa810 [mem: 557fd23781c8] (BIO dump follows)
ssl_engine_io.c(1998): +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
ssl_engine_io.c(2037): | 0000: 0b 00 13 cd 00 13 ca 00-06 d9 30 82 06 d5 30 82  ..........0...0. |
ssl_engine_io.c(2037): | 0010: 04 bd a0 03 02 01 02 02-12 11 21 1f 9d 56 1c 0f  ..........!..V.. |
ssl_engine_io.c(2037): | 0020: 7d 5f 63 7c 90 39 0d 57-60 b2 75 30 0d 06 09 2a  }_c|.9.W`.u0...* |

... continues for a few hundred lines
```

while the request from the client that doesn't go through doesn't produce any of that.

- BUT, The client certificate can't really be missing from the orignal requests because it used to go through and our application was able to recognize it.
- We tested both types of clients (working and not working) with the same certificate, so that's not the problem.
- We used ssllabs.com to analyze our servers. We saw that our new implementation doesn't support TLS 1.0 and 1.1 but from what we saw when we made some tests, a request to the new server with an old TLS implementation create a very specific error message, nothing about a missing certificate.
- ssllabs also revealed that our old server accepted a whole lot more of Cipher Suites than what our current server does. Though I don't think this is correlated to our problem.
- The new server doesn't have SSL2 compatibility while the old one does.

We're a bit at a loss, as nobody here is specialized in this kind of subject. If you see some things in my question that doesn't make sense or need clarifications, feel free to ask. (I may indeed be confused on some things, as I said this is not my domain)

I'll update if we find more information.

Comment: You should get hold of one of the failing client certificates and look at it to see if something is unusual about it.

Comment: The thing is, the same certificate used with different clients (a nagios check_http or a request sent with SoapUI) will achieve different results: one goes through and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old topic and I'm not 100% sure, but I think the problem was indeed the TLS version.
Some of the clients used very old versions that couldn't communicate with us anymore.

I'll close the question.